# Given word pattern and its offset, find its word position/order in the sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of dict like this:

```
{'content': '@aaaaaaaaaaa People are going to find it hard to believe that Miliband makes it up as he goes along more than Osborne.',
 'entities': [{'named_entity': 'miliband', 'offset': 62}]}
```

So I have entities such as 'miliband', which matches with 'Miliband.' (i.e. the first miliband) in the content (I used `re.compile(r'\b({0})\b')` for matching), and offset of its starting letter. I want to find out the word position of 'Miliband.' within the sentence, i.e. 'Miliband.' is the 11th word in the sentence.

Is there anyway I can do that?? I suppose i will have to tokenize the sentence first, but how do I utilize the offset to identify the correct matching word and thus its position in the tokenized list...

Thanks!

Update:
Regarding special characters/ punctuations preceding the entity word. e.g., '#miliband' and `s = 'hello world #miliband'; pos = 13; pos_word = len(s[:62].split()) = 3` which should be 2 (starts from 0), because of '#'. Is there any way the program use this offset (i.e. 13) and identifies this character is within the offset range of the third tokenised word '#miliband' therefore = 2?

Comment: What's your expected output? Why you want the regex to match the first one?

Comment: my expect output is simply the position of the matching word, in the case of 'Miliband.', -> 11.  Because i want to match those have special characters/ punctuations preceding or succeeding 'miliband' as well

Comment: well, as i see you got two different problems.   one is the appropriate regexp to match what you are searching for.  'milliband.', '#milliband'.  naively, i would somewhat consider any non-alphanum character to serve as a boundary to your words.  not just \bxxx\b.  the second is the split counting to find your word position.  i don't think these are separate concerns, and i don't think foregoing regexes, much as they are tricky is the way to go.  your word boundary pattern find should probably go into my naive split.  regex allows for multiple splits, use those.

Comment: if you think blanks and #s are word splits, then they belong as such in your initial regex that finds 62 (which is the wrong answer) and then the second one that finds word position.  see if you want recycle one regex to the other and that leads me to think the regex package may even hold a full answer.  i.e. split by your search pattern, milliband, + the boundary qualifier \b'#.  then split by boundary qualifier \b# to find the wordpos.  those are related questions and use unit testing to tease out your code.  regex is awesomely powerful.  if code is tricky and i feel dumb=>pull out unittest.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.  Hopefully this will be helpful, however.  You first need to split the sentence, and then use index to find the first occurrence of the word within the list.

```
d = {'content': 'People are going to find it hard to believe Miliband. Miliband makes it up as he goes along more than Osborne.', 'entities': [{'named_entity': 'miliband', 'offset': 62}]}

>>> d['content'].split().index('Miliband')
10
```

Note that the offset of 62 gives the second Miliband.

```
>>> d['content'][:62]
'People are going to find it hard to believe Miliband. Miliband'
```

Using the offset from the dictionary:

```
>>> len(d['content'][0:d['entities'][0]['offset']].split())
11
```

Comment: ah, nice catch.  wonder if it was the "." after the first Miliband vs the regex wanting blanks...  A "\b|\." , or whatever arcana regexery is required, might sort that out.

Comment: ha my bad, i didnt want to include the @reply. the original tweet is '@jamieszymko People are going to find it hard to believe that Miliband makes it up as he goes along more than Osborne. #marr/#marrshow'

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, use your already-found position (62).  That's your position, all you need to do is count tokens up to the word you've matched there.

```
s="People are going to find it hard to believe Miliband. Miliband makes it up as he goes along more than Osborne.',"

pos = 62

pos_word = len(s[:62].split())

print pos_word
```

which gives 11.  As always, you may need to -1 or +1 to get the number straight, but that should work.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have issues regarding special characters/ punctuations preceding the entity word. e.g., '#miliband' and `s = 'hello world #miliband'; pos = 13; pos_word = len(s[:62].split()) = 3` which should be 2, because of '#'

Comment: is there any way the program use this offset (i.e. 13) and identifies this character is within the third tokenised word '#miliband' therefore = 2?